# Bipolar stepper motor spins very slowly and makes a loud noise

Tags: raspberry-pi, stepper-motor, stepper-driver, python

I got a custom PCB. I am using `DRV8428P` driver ([here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8428e.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1642596244391&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D26%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fdrv8428e) is the datasheet) for a stepper motor. The problem I am facing is not being able to have the stepper rotate faster than 5 rpm. Also, the stepper makes a very loud noise.

Here is the schematic of my stepper controller:

[image]

Here are the specs of the stepper motor:

[image]

[image]

Here is how I wired up my stepper to the custom PCB:

[image]

My controller is Raspberry Pi Zero and I am using Python to drive the stepper:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

delay = 0.0005 #time to settle

AIN1 = 21 # GPIO21
AIN2 = 26 # GPIO26
BIN1 = 20 # GPIO20
BIN2 = 8  # GPIO8

def setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(AIN1, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.setup(AIN2, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.setup(BIN1, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.setup(BIN2, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)


setup()

def setStep(w1, w2, w3, w4):
  GPIO.output(AIN1, w1)
  GPIO.output(AIN2, w2)
  GPIO.output(BIN1, w3)
  GPIO.output(BIN2, w4)
  time.sleep(delay)

try:
    while 1:
        setStep(1,0,1,0)
        setStep(0,1,1,0)
        setStep(0,1,0,1)
        setStep(1,0,0,1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
GPIO.cleanup()
```

When I decrease the delay value, the stepper mostly won't move but vibrates. The delay value that seems to work is `0.0005`. However, the stepper makes a loud noise and barely rotates. I uploaded a short video of the stepper here: https://streamable.com/6kyayx.

I am not sure how get the stepper to spin as fast as 150 rpm as it is stated in the stepper's specs. I also have a hard time translating the hints to Python code, which are given in the steppers specs regarding high torque and initial phase setup.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this really a 5V motor, attempting to drive with 24V?

Comment: `DVDD` is 5v (measured it myself).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check with a multimeter that red-yellow is one coil and blue-orange is the other.

The chart shows that you've got to start the stepper at about 500 Hz and ramp up. Starting at too high a frequency will cause it to stall.

500 Hz would correspond to 2 ms per step rather than 0.5 ms which is what your `delay = 0.0005` is giving you.

Comment: how did you convert 500 Hz to 2 ms delay in this case? Can you please share the formula?

Comment: @mr-ma, I imagine the formula was: freq period = 1/freq. You'll find that on about page 1 of many electronics books and you should take the time to learn such electronics basics if you hope to get your circuit working successfully.

Comment: @mr-ma. Thanks for accepting my answer. Was 2 ms the solution? As TonyM pointed out, \$ t = \frac 1 f \$ where \$t\$ is the  periodic time and \$f\$ is the frequency. (Hertz means cycles per second, after all.)

Comment: Does it work now? What was the solution?